# How to change the alignment of an equation in a gather environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath, gather

I am using the `gather environment` to write the equations for my report.
By default, the `gather environment` centers equations. For example, if I write:

```
Furthermore, in a Markov chain, it is assumed that transitional 
probabilities are *stationary*. Meaning, the probability of a 
future outcome will always have the same probability, given the present.
\begin{gather}
Pr\{X_1=j | X_0=i\} = Pr\{ X_{n+1}=j | X_n=i \}
\end{gather}
```

Then, the outcome will be:

[image]

I am required however to **not** center my equations, but instead place them after 1 indentation only. Like this (achieved with Word):

[image]

How can I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Since you're already loading the `amsmath` package (in order to use the `gather` environment), all you have to do now is load that package with the option `fleqn`.

Comment: Could you give me more details, please? Where should I be writing `fleqn` exactly?

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted. To load the `amsmath` package with the option `fleqn`, one should write `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- Since you're loading the `amsmath` package anyway (in order to use the `gather` environment), all you have to do now in order to achieve your formatting objective is to load that package with the option `fleqn` ("flush left equations"):

  ```
  \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
  ```
- The amount of indentation of a flush-left equation from the left-hand margin is controlled by the parameter `\mathindent`. The default value of this parameter is `25pt minus 25pt`, i.e., it's a so-called "rubber" length. (Here with some possibility for shrinkage, but not for expansion.)

  To change the value of this parameter to, say, `1em`, all you need to do is execute the instruction

  ```
  \setlength\mathindent{1em}
  ```
- It's considered poor LaTeX form to use `gather` -- or, for that matter, `align` -- environments for single-line displayed equations. Do use the `equation` environment for single-line equations.
- Don't enter the symbol `|` directly to denote "conditional on". Instead, please use the macro `\mid`, which is programmed to insert a bit of whitespace on both sides of `|`.
- Since "Pr" denotes "probability" (unless I'm very badly mistaken...), consider writing `\Pr` instead of just `Pr`. The `\Pr` macro typesets the letters "Pr" using upright roman characters, which is considered (from a typographic point of view) to be desirable for math operators. (Other examples of LaTeX math operators are `\log`, `\exp`, `\sin`, `lim`, and `\det`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{showframe} % to indicate margins
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather} % not elegant
Pr\{X_1=j | X_0=i\} = Pr\{ X_{n+1}=j | X_n=i \}
\end{gather}

\setlength\mathindent{1em}
%% 3 differences from above: 
%% (a) use 'equation' env.; (b) use \Pr; (c) use \mid.
\begin{equation}
\Pr\{X_1=j \mid X_0=i\} = \Pr\{ X_{n+1}=j \mid X_n=i \}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is such a detailed and brilliant answer, full of great pieces of advice. Everything you said was correct. Thank you very much! I will follow all of them. I only started learning LaTeX last November and did not expect to be writing my thesis using it, but here I am. Thank you again.

Comment: @Aziz - Many thanks for letting me know that you found my additional comments useful. Good luck and best wishes with your thesis.